# Protect CRTP pattern from stack overflowing in "pure virtual" calls

Tags: c++, crtp, pure-virtual, virtual-functions

Consider the following standard CRTP example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Derived>
struct Base {
    void f() { static_cast<Derived *>(this)->f(); }
    void g() { static_cast<Derived *>(this)->g(); }
};

struct Foo : public Base<Foo> {
    void f() { std::cout << 42 << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.f(); // just OK
    foo.g(); // this will stack overflow and segfault
}
```

If this was regular virtual inheritance I could have mark virtual `f` and `g` methods as pure like

```
struct Base {
    virtual void f() = 0;
    virtual void g() = 0;
};
```

and get a compile time error about `Foo` being abstract. But CRTP offers no such protection. Can I implement it somehow? Runtime check is acceptable too. I thought about comparing `this->f` pointer with `static_cast<Derived *>(this)->f`, but didn't manage to make it work.

Comment: I don't know if this is a standard-defined behavior, but you can `static_assert` inside `Base::g` that `&Derived::g != &Base<Derived>::g`.

Comment: This appears to work aswell: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80021ad0bfb7aa47

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That is clever!  You should write up an answer.

Comment: @Yakk done, thanks. Clang's error message is suboptimal, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is another possibility:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Derived>
struct Base {
    auto f() { return static_cast<Derived *>(this)->f(); }
    auto g() { return static_cast<Derived *>(this)->g(); }
};

struct Foo : public Base<Foo> {
    void f() { std::cout << 42 << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.f(); // just OK
    foo.g(); // this will not compile
}
```

For GCC, it gives a pretty clear error message (*"error: use of 'auto Base::g() [with Derived = Foo]' before deduction of 'auto'"*), while for Clang, it gives a slightly less readable infinitely recursing template instantiation of `Base<Foo>::g`, with `g` instantiating itself but eventually ending in an error.

Comment: That is actually rare, that clang gives a worse error message than gcc, in my experience.

Comment: Latest version of clang [seems to produce](https://godbolt.org/g/ozbnVB) something close to gcc (clang >= 3.9.1).

Comment: The error message might be less than perfect, but you can't argue with the simplicity of the solution!

Comment: Nice one, but is there possibility to adapt it for C++11?

Comment: @uranix a similar approach can be applied, but then both the error message and the code become much uglier: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7b767fcc6ce94d6

Answer (score 25):

You can assert at compile time that the two pointers to member functions are different, e.g.:

```
template<class Derived>
struct Base {
    void g() {
        static_assert(&Derived::g != &Base<Derived>::g,
                      "Derived classes must implement g()."); 
        static_cast<Derived *>(this)->g(); 
    }
};
```

Comment: You where uncertain if this was standard defined behaviour in a comment above.  Care to expand on that in this answer?

Comment: @Yakk I was not sure about the rule (conversion / comparison) for pointer to member functions between base / derived class. I checked the standard (in particular [conv.mem#2]) and some questions on SO and I am pretty confident that this is valid. But if you have reason to believe this is not, feel free to explain - If this is incorrect, I'll remove this answer quickly.

Answer (score 13):

You could use this solution, you can have pure "non-virtual abstract" function, and it maps as much as possible to CRTP this [recommendation of H. Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm):

```
template<class Derived>
struct Base
  {
  void f(){static_cast<Derived*>(this)->do_f();}
  void g(){static_cast<Derived*>(this)->do_g();}

  private:
  //Derived must implement do_f
  void do_f()=delete;
  //do_g as a default implementation
  void do_g(){}
  };

struct derived
  :Base<derived>
  {
  friend struct Base<derived>;

  private:
  void do_f(){}
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider doing something like this instead. You can make `Derived` a member and either supply it as a template parameter directly each time you instantiate a `Base` or else use a *type alias* as I have done in this example:

```
template<class Derived>
struct Base {
    void f() { d.f(); }
    void g() { d.g(); }
private:
    Derived d;
};

struct FooImpl {
    void f() { std::cout << 42 << std::endl; }
};

using Foo = Base<FooImpl>;

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.f(); // OK
    foo.g(); // compile time error
}
```

Of course `Derived` is no longer *derived* so you might pick a better name for it.

Comment: The name isn't as bad as the changed semantics. One can't substitute `Derived` for `Base<Derived>` anymore. So generic functions a-la `template<typename T> void foo(Base<T>&) { }` will not work anymore.

Comment: @StoryTeller It doesn't pretend to be semantically identical. It is marked as a possible (safe) alternative which is good in  many situations. (I use it all the time)

Comment: This works, but simply isn't CRTP, which is about inheritance. Instead, this answer uses composition.

Comment: @davidhigh My answer doesn't pretend to be CRTP. It is offered as an alternative solution.

Comment: RIght, you clearly said "instead" :-) ... nevertheless this could be missed in reading over it.